# How to convert database table entry to an enum?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework, .net-3.5

In my web application I have many tables which have fixed data, when I use them in my project then I use enums for that purpose.

I want to convert these tables to enums automatically.

After little looking up I did this by using T4, TextTemplates: [see my code here.](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/e2fe6ffab1a10deef59c)

But I wanted to do this by using Entity Framework, according to the [official documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/jj248772) enums are supported in .NET Framework 4.5 and above, but I am using .NET 3.5.

How can I achieve this, potentially by using custom text templates?

Comment: I believe your question data is in error.  netfx has supported enums since version 1.0.  Are you perhaps confusing netfx and Entity Framework?

Comment: I am not sure about that...but still how can I convert classes to enums using code first approch on EF.

Comment: You should create a small example and put it in your question, to clearly illustrate your issue. Posting links to full source code is not acceptable here. Being desperate is not an excuse to go against the rules. Please improve your question (it will also increase the probability of receiving any valuable help) - otherwise [it may be closed even though it has a bounty](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/281120/2642204).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally solved it. Made a T4 template and replaced that with the default generated tt file.

My code is [here, please star it if you found it helpful and add comments in case of help or suggestions.](https://gist.github.com/MrHmP/035897f14f77f93a54d3)

Comment: Please skip the "advertisement" of your profile on other site, and don't post answers that rely almost entirely on a link. You should include the relevant parts of the code here in your answer. Thanks.